# RDO unable to boot VM with disk size specified

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, openstack-nova, rhel7

I have packstack-allinone setup on my RHEL7.1 trial for Juno release.

I am facing problem while launching VM(for ex: cirros) with a disk size mentioned in flavor. If there is 0gb disk size then VM are getting launched but not for higher flavor sizes.

I also observe that when I do this, openstack-nova-compute service goes down which I observed when I checked using nova-manage service list with nova-compute being XXX making me restart the service everytime I try this scenario. The compute logs doesn't throw any error, it just gets stuck at "Creating image".

Is there any Filesystem issue which i missing to be configured? I am new to this, so please help.

PS: I run all commands with "root" user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with esxi. Esxi needs to be 5.5v to support RHEL7x Since mine was 5.1v it only supported RHEL6x.

After upgrading esxi5.1 to 5.5v it worked fine.